# $\sqrt{I} \subset I(Z(I))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $I$ be a ideal of $k[x_1,...,x_2]$. Show that $\sqrt{I} \subset I(Z(I))$.

Observing that $J \subset I(Z(J))$, for any ideal $J$ of $k[x_1,...,x_2]$ and that $Z(\sqrt{I})=Z(I)$, we have completed the desired.

However, the problem says: Give an example where inclusion is proper.

And I'm not being able to end the problem. Anyone have a tip?

Comment: There must be some sort of typo, because this is always an equality. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz

Comment: Maybe the question that was meant was a situation when $I\subset I(Z(I))$ is proper?

Comment: Maybe $k$ is not algebraically closed? @AlexMathers

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Good point! Feeling silly now

Comment: Yes, I wrote badly ... it should be: Give an example where $I \subset I(Z(I))$ is proper. Otherwise, as @AlexMathers said, Nullstellensatz resolves instantly. Lord Shark the Unknown  was accurate. Thanks for the correction to both of you.